# is the function injective?

Tags: functions, solution-verification

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = (x-3)(x+7)$

$x≠y ⇒ f(x)≠f(y)$
$x=-1$ and $y = 1$
$f(-1) = (-1-3)(-1+7) = -24$
$f(1)=(1-3)(1+7) = -16$\

The function is an injective since  $x≠y ⇒ f(x)≠f(y)$.
is this correct?

Comment: A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is injective (1-1) if and only if it is monotone (strictly increasing or strictly decreasing).

Comment: No.  To show that a function is injective, you must show that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.  To show that is not injective, you must find $x_1 \neq x_2$ such that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  **Hint:**  What are the $x$-intercepts of the graph?

Comment: in other words, a polynomial of even degree cannot be injective

Comment: The graph of the function is a parabola so ...

Comment: @N.F.Taussig To clarify though for OP: a function is injective if and only if $x\neq y\implies f(x)\neq f(y)$. It's just more common to prove the contraposition.

Comment: @ElliotG  Of course, that must be true for any $x, y$ in the domain with $x \neq y$.  Alex made the mistake of showing that a particular choice of $x$ and $y$ satisfied the condition $x \neq y \implies f(x) \neq f(y)$, which proves nothing.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I think the point is that you said that in order to prove injectivity "you *must* show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$" (emphasis added); but in fact that is not *required*: it may be possible to prove it other ways. I think the objection is to "must" in both sentences. You probably mean that in order to prove it in this manner, you would have to establish it for arbitrary $x$ and $y$, so one must/should not do it for specific values. But the way it is written makes it sound like you are prescribing the method of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof does not seem to make sense. If you want to prove that a function $f: A \to B$ is injective, you need to take two elements $x,y \in A$ satisfying $f(x)=f(y)$ and show that $x$ must be equal to $y$. It is not possible to achieve this for your problem because $f(3)=f(-7)=0$ and obviously $3\ne -7$. Hence the function that you have been given is not injective.

Comment: One may prove that a function is injective by proving that if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$. The proof by contrapositive that you mention is not the only way to establish injectivity, so saying that one "needs" to do it that way is not accurate.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I do not disagree. The "need" here is for taking two elements and not the need to complete the proof the way I mentioned it.

Comment: Please read what you wrote, then: it reads as if you are specifying that the method you mention is the *required* method. "To prove `blah` you need to `X`" definitely sounds like you are saying that `X` is **the** way, the only way, in which `blah` may be proven.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove that $f$ is injective, you usually have two ways of doing it directly:

1. Prove that **for every possible choice** of $x$ and $y$, if $x\neq y$, then $f(x)\neq y$; or
2. The contrapositive: prove **for every possible choice** of $x$ and $y$, if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=y$.

(There are often other ways of showing a function is injective, but that is neither here not there for the purposes of what you are doing...)

In both cases you need to show that something is true *for every possible choice* of $x$ and $y$. You have shown that 1 is true for *specific* choice of $x$ and $y$, so you have not actually proven that 1 is true.

In fact, this function is *not* injective, so you won't be able to prove 1. In order to show that 1 is *false*, it is enough to show that there exist **one** choice of $x$ and $y$ for which $x\neq y$ but $f(x)=f(y)$. You may be getting confused with *that*.

To show that something *always* happens, it is never enough to show it happens once.

To show that something does **not** always happen, it is enough to exhibit it not happening *once*.

You are trying to show something *always* happens, by showing it happens once. That is not a valid proof.